# modify thmbox.sty

Tags: thmtools, thmbox

I want to modify `thmbox.sty` as it would not underline the optional key :

```
    \begin{myenvthmboxname}[text I don't want to underline]
        But I want to underline the title of the box.
    \end{myenvthmboxname}
```

I tried some modifications, but i failed : if I put the option `undeline=true` it underlines the environnement title and "text I don't want to underline".
Any ideas ?

Comment: Try `nounderline` option.

Comment: No, I want to underline the title of the box, but not the optional argument.
If I put nounderline, nothing is underlined.

Comment: see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of tries to understand the code, I found a solution. Later I'll try to explain what I did. In resume I passed the optional argument to the head box outside the box which determines the width for the rule.

[image]

**`thmbox.sty`** (copy and save as `thmbox.sty` in the same folder as your `tex` file)

```
%%
%% This is file `thmbox.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% thmbox.dtx 
%% 
%% This is the thmbox package.
%% (c) Emmanuel Beffara, 2002--2005 (LPPL)
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{thmbox}[2005/04/24 v2.0 fancy theorem outlining]
\RequirePackage{keyval}
\newcommand\thmboxoptions{\setkeys{thmbox}}
\let\thmbox@style=M
\define@key{thmbox}{style}{\let\thmbox@style=#1}
\define@key{thmbox}{S}[]{\let\thmbox@style=S}
\define@key{thmbox}{M}[]{\let\thmbox@style=M}
\define@key{thmbox}{L}[]{\let\thmbox@style=L}
\newdimen\thmbox@leftmargin  \thmbox@leftmargin=\parindent
\newdimen\thmbox@rightmargin \thmbox@rightmargin=0pt
\newdimen\thmbox@hskip       \thmbox@hskip=.4em
\newdimen\thmbox@vskip       \thmbox@vskip=.4em
\newdimen\thmbox@thickness   \thmbox@thickness=.6pt
\define@key{thmbox}{leftmargin}{\thmbox@leftmargin=#1\relax}
\define@key{thmbox}{rightmargin}{\thmbox@rightmargin=#1\relax}
\define@key{thmbox}{hskip}{\thmbox@hskip=#1\relax}
\define@key{thmbox}{vskip}{\thmbox@vskip=#1\relax}
\define@key{thmbox}{thickness}{\thmbox@thickness=#1\relax}
\newif\ifthmbox@cut
\thmbox@cuttrue
\define@key{thmbox}{cut}[true]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\ifthmbox@cut\csname if#1\endcsname}
\define@key{thmbox}{nocut}[]{\thmbox@cutfalse}
\DeclareOption{cut}{\thmbox@cuttrue}
\DeclareOption{nocut}{\thmbox@cutfalse}
\newif\ifthmbox@underline
\thmbox@underlinetrue
\define@key{thmbox}{underline}[true]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\ifthmbox@underline\csname if#1\endcsname}
\define@key{thmbox}{nounderline}[]{\thmbox@underlinefalse}
\DeclareOption{underline}{\thmbox@underlinetrue}
\DeclareOption{nounderline}{\thmbox@underlinefalse}
\newcommand\thmbox@headstyle[2]{\bfseries\boldmath#1 #2}
\define@key{thmbox}{headstyle}{\def\thmbox@headstyle##1##2{#1}}
\newcommand\thmbox@titlestyle[1]{ 
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
\else
\normalfont(\textit{#1\/})%
\fi}
\define@key{thmbox}{titlestyle}{\def\thmbox@titlestyle##1{#1}}
\newcommand\thmbox@bodystyle{\slshape\noindent}
\define@key{thmbox}{bodystyle}{\def\thmbox@bodystyle{#1}}
\newif\ifthmbox@newtheorem
\thmbox@newtheoremtrue
\DeclareOption{nothm}{\thmbox@newtheoremfalse}
\DeclareOption*{\expandafter\thmboxoptions\expandafter{\CurrentOption}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\newbox\thmbox@box
\newbox\thmbox@box@
\newbox\thmbox@box@@% <---- NEW
\newdimen\thmbox@dim
\def\thmbox@put#1{
  \vskip\z@%
  \noindent%
  \hbox{%
    {\dimen0=\thmbox@leftmargin%
     \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@hskip%
     \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@thickness%
     \hskip\dimen0}%
    \vrule width \thmbox@thickness%
    \hskip\thmbox@hskip%
    \box#1%
    \ifx\thmbox@style L%
      \hskip\thmbox@hskip%
      \vrule width \thmbox@thickness%
    \fi}%
  \par\nobreak}
\def\thmbox@start{%
  \ifthmbox@cut%
    \ifdim\pagetotal>\vsize%
      \thmbox@dim=2\vsize%
    \else%
      \thmbox@dim=\vsize%
    \fi%
    \advance\thmbox@dim -\pagetotal%
    \ifdim\thmbox@dim>\ht\thmbox@box%
      \thmbox@put\thmbox@box%
    \else%
      \setbox\thmbox@box@=\vsplit\thmbox@box to \thmbox@dim%
      \thmbox@put\thmbox@box@%
      \thmbox@page%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \thmbox@put\thmbox@box%
  \fi}
\def\thmbox@page{%
  \ifvoid\thmbox@box%
  \else%
    \eject%
    \ifdim\vsize<\ht\thmbox@box%
      \setbox\thmbox@box@=\vsplit\thmbox@box to \vsize%
      \thmbox@put\thmbox@box@%
      \thmbox@page%
    \else%
      \thmbox@put\thmbox@box%
    \fi%
  \fi}
\def\thmbox@head#1#2{%
  \par\noindent\vbox{%
    \setbox\thmbox@box@=\hbox{%
      \vrule width 0mm height 0mm depth \thmbox@vskip %
      #1}%
%%%% new box to store the optional argument
    \setbox\thmbox@box@@=\hbox{%
%      \vrule width 0mm height 0mm depth \thmbox@vskip%
      \thmbox@titlestyle{#2} }% optional argument     
    \hbox{\copy\thmbox@box@\copy\thmbox@box@@}% hbox to put both on the same line
    \ifthmbox@underline%
      \hrule width \wd\thmbox@box@ height \thmbox@thickness%
    \fi }%
  \hrule height 0mm\relax}
\def\thmbox@tail{%
  \hrule height 0mm%
  \ifx\thmbox@style M%
    \thmbox@dim=1cm%
  \else\ifx\thmbox@style L%
    \thmbox@dim=\hsize%
    \advance\thmbox@dim-\thmbox@leftmargin%
    \advance\thmbox@dim-\thmbox@rightmargin%
    \advance\thmbox@dim2\thmbox@hskip%
    \advance\thmbox@dim2\thmbox@thickness%
  \fi\fi%
  \noindent%
  {\dimen0=\thmbox@leftmargin%
   \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@hskip%
   \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@thickness%
   \hskip\dimen0}%
  \vrule width \thmbox@dim height \thmbox@thickness%
  \par}
\newenvironment{thmbox}[3][]{%
  \parskip\z@%
  \setkeys{thmbox}{#1}%
  \ifx\thmbox@style S\else\ifx\thmbox@style M\else\ifx\thmbox@style L\else%
    \PackageWarning{thmbox}{\thmbox@style\ is not a valid style for
      \string\thmbox, using M}%
    \let\thmbox@style=M%
  \fi\fi\fi%
  \thmbox@head{{#2}}{#3}\nobreak\relax%  <--- used 2nd argument in head
  \thmbox@dim=\hsize%
  \advance\thmbox@dim-\leftskip%
  \advance\thmbox@dim-\rightskip%
  \setbox\thmbox@box=\vbox\bgroup%
    \hsize=\thmbox@dim%
    \advance\hsize -\thmbox@leftmargin%
    \advance\hsize -\thmbox@rightmargin%
    \textwidth=\hsize%
    \linewidth=\hsize%
    \vskip\thmbox@vskip%
    \begingroup}{\endgroup%
    \vskip\thmbox@vskip%
  \egroup%
  \thmbox@start%
  \ifx\thmbox@style S\else\thmbox@tail\fi%
  \@endparenv}
\newenvironment{leftbar}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{thmbox}{#1}%
  \par\vskip\thmbox@vskip%
  \setbox\thmbox@box=\vbox\bgroup%
    \hsize=\textwidth%
    \advance\hsize -\thmbox@leftmargin%
    \advance\hsize -\thmbox@rightmargin%
    \begingroup}{\endgroup%
    \vskip\thmbox@vskip%
  \egroup%
  \thmbox@start%
  \vskip\thmbox@vskip\par}
\def\newboxtheorem{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\thmbox@newA}{\thmbox@newA[]}}%
\def\thmbox@newA[#1]#2{%
  \def\thmbox@temp##1{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\thmbox@newC{#2}}{\thmbox@newD{#2}}}
\def\thmbox@newC#1[#2]#3{%
  \expandafter\thmbox@new\expandafter{\thmbox@temp{####1}}{#1}{#3}{#2}}
\def\thmbox@newD#1#2{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\thmbox@newE{#1}{#2}}{%
    \newcounter{#1}%
    \expandafter\thmbox@new\expandafter{\thmbox@temp{####1}}{#1}{#2}{#1}}}
\def\thmbox@newE#1#2[#3]{%
  \newcounter{#1}[#3]%
  \expandafter\def\csname the#1\endcsname{%
    \csname the#3\endcsname.\arabic{#1}}
  \expandafter\thmbox@new\expandafter{\thmbox@temp{####1}}{#1}{#2}{#1}}
\def\thmbox@new#1#2#3#4{%
  \expandafter\def\csname#2\endcsname{%
    \setkeys{thmbox}{#1}%
    \@ifnextchar[{\thmbox@beginA{#3}{#4}}{%
      \thmbox@begin{#3}{#4}{}}}%
  \expandafter\def\csname end#2\endcsname{%
    \endthmbox\smallbreak}}
\def\thmbox@beginA#1#2[#3]{%
  \thmbox@begin{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\thmbox@begin#1#2#3{%
  \medbreak%
  \refstepcounter{#2}%
  \thmbox{\thmbox@headstyle{#1}{\csname the#2\endcsname}}{#3}% 3rd used outside the thmbox
  \thmbox@bodystyle\ignorespaces}
\ifthmbox@newtheorem
\let\newtheorem\newboxtheorem
\fi
\def\example{}
\@ifundefined{examplename}{\def\examplename{Example}}{}
\renewenvironment{example}[1][\examplename]{%
  \par\smallbreak\small%
  \list{\hspace\labelsep\textbf{#1\,:}}{%
    \leftmargin=\parindent%
    \labelwidth=\parindent}%
  \item\relax}{%
  \endlist}
\def\proof{}
\@ifundefined{proofname}{\def\proofname{Proof}}{}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][]{%
  \small%
  \list{\hspace\labelsep\textbf{\proofname\ #1\unskip\,:}}{%
    \topsep=\smallskipamount%
    \partopsep=0pt%
    \leftmargin=\parindent%
    \rightmargin=\parindent%
    \listparindent=\parindent%
    \labelwidth=\parindent}%
  \item\relax\ignorespaces}%
 {\parskip\z@%
  \par\noindent%
  \setbox\thmbox@box=\hbox{%
    \kern .5em\vbox{%
      \hrule width .7em height .7em
      \vskip\baselineskip}}%
  \wd\thmbox@box=0mm%
  \ht\thmbox@box=0mm%
  \hfill\box\thmbox@box%
  \endlist\par}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `thmbox.sty'.
```

Comment: Well done on hacking the package, but I would strongly recommend *not* to keep the same name.  Renaming it to something different would be much better.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer, this is why I suggested to save it on the same folder instead of replace the original one. Since I changed a lot of lines, it is not possible to use a simple `\makeatletter \makeatother` in preamble. But also your idea is nice.

Comment: I have to insist: it is not only bad practice to keep the same name when you change someone’s else package, it is actually illegal if that package uses LPPL as its licence, which is the case here.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer, I have to go now. Tomorrow I'll edit the code to change the name since we need to change other lines to above warnings on compilation. Change only the name is not enough. See you.

Comment: @Sigur, Thanks !! You've done a very good job ! But can you please put somewhere a `\ifx` or something else to avoid the empty `()` when the optionnal argument is not set ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @math45, I'll do my best to fix this. Please, wait.

Comment: For the optional argument, put `\newcommand\thmbox@titlestyle[1]{ 
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  %
  \else
  \normalfont\textsf{(\textit{#1\/})}%
  \fi}`
do the trick.

Comment: @math45, ok. You can edit the answer, if you want. I'm a little busy to work on the code. Thanks.